# NumberFormatException Trim Variable

Tags: trim, numberformatexception

TITLE = Float.parseFloat(dataRecord.get("TITLE"));
String trimmed = TITLE.substring(0,40); // get the first 40 chars.

"Title" can be a numerical and nonnumerical variable.  Trying to trim my string "TITLE" to 40 characters

The error message was: NumberFormatException (line 4): For input string: "New Travel 3PC 28"/24"/20" Rolling Expandable Upright Luggage Set"-- Method Invocation Float.parseFloat

Answer (score 0):

The error message says the value resulted from `dataRecord.get("TITLE")` is not a number as `Float.parseFloat()` method expects. In fact, the value that is passed to this function which has caused error has also been shown which is `"New Travel 3PC 28"/24"/20" Rolling Expandable Upright Luggage Set"`.
So, this error has nothing to do with trimming the string. You must check why the value in `"TITLE"` field of your record is not what you expect to be.